# IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status - The agent crashed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an existing iOS Project in Xcode 10.2.1 on macOS 10.14.4. The uses mainly Objectiv-C but also some Swift Pods (v. 1.5.2). Recently I have also added the first Swift based ViewController using Swift 5.

**The Problem:**

When working on the XIB file of this Swift bases ViewController after a short time the following error message is shown in the Xcode sidebar:

> IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for
>   ViewXYZ (abc-de-123): The agent crashed

As soon as there error occur no changes in the Interface Builder (added view, changed colors, text, etc.) are shown anymore. When I re-open the XIB file it only show grey view placeholders instead of the real content.

The problem can only be solved by re-starting Xcode but when working on the XIB again it shows up after again after just a few moment.

**Things that did NOT work**

Since the problem is realted to IB Designabales I checked these first. Within the ViewController I am using two different custom views which are implemented in Objective-C and marked as `IB_DESIGNABLE`.

These views have not been changed recently and it was never a problem to use them before. Removing all custom code from these views did not change the problem. Thus there seems to be nothing wrong with the implementation.

I found other topics dealing with similar issues, but none of the different solutions worked for me:

- Re-starting the Mac, re-starting Xcode, cleaning the build folder or deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` does NOT solve the problem
- Adding [this code to the pod file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520336/777861) does NOT solve the problem
- Adding [all `UIView` constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322851/777861) to the views as proposed here does NOT solve the problem.
- Xcode shows that the designables are up to date and does NOT offer a debug button ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257488/777861))
- The views do not have orphant outlets
- Re-creating the XIB from scratch let to the same issue
- Not using the Bundle or other device specific code within the custom views did NOT solve the problem. As described before I removed ALL custom code from the classes so that they where simple `UIView` subclasses without any changes.

**So far nothing I tried had any effect. However, most answers I found are quite old. Are there are any *new* proposals to solve this issue?**

Comment: Did you check the crash log in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`? Sometimes an `IBDesignable` crashes because of the code implementation

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that I can find the logs there. It seems that there is a problem with some 3rd party control (which has worked without any problems so far...) I will investigate this further and edit the question if necessary.