# IB Designables for storyboard UITableViewCell: Failed to render and update auto layout status for CountdownViewController The agent crashed

Tags: ios, uitableview, ibdesignable

Seems like I am using `@IBDesignbale` wrong, but why?

I want to use a combination of `IBDesignable` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` to inject some data into my `MyTableViewCell` so it can display some dummy data(in this sample project, just set the `dummyView.backgroundColor = .red` ) in my storyboard.

My current setup:

1, I guess the usual setup for a tableview using storyboard. TableView inside a view and dragged a `UITableViewCell` into the tableview.

2, marked my `MyTableViewCell` `@IBDesignable`

3, override `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` inside the `MyTableViewCell` setting the `dummyView` backgroundColor

error:

Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): The agent crashed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `dummyView` is an `IBOutlet` and is implicitly unwrapped. `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` will be called before `dummyView` is initialized. You can prevent a crash by changing your code to `dummyView?.backgroundColor = .red` but then nothing will be rendered because `dummyView == nil`.

It doesn't make a ton of sense to mix `IBDesignable` with `IBOutlet`. In general, `IBDesignable` is meant to make run time layout and drawing visible at design time. But `IBOutlets` are necessarily already visible at design time. This might however be desirable in a xib. For a discussion of that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26886143/5442445) and [here.](http://justabeech.com/2014/07/27/xcode-6-live-rendering-from-nib/)